# Still confused about Goals in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I kind of understand most things in Maven, but trying to understand goals is very frustrating. The main problem is that Maven seems to want to hide everything and anything to do with Goals.

- If I have a **plugin** with an **execution**, and this execution has a **goal**,
  does the goal attach itself somewhere near particular other goals?
- How does it know which phase it belongs in?
- Does it somehow replace some other goal?

Case in point :

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>                    
            <execution>
                <id>wsimport-from-jdk</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>${tool.wsimport}</executable>
                    <wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlUrl>http://WorkPC:8080/server-web/AirlineWS?wsdl</wsdlUrl>     
                    </wsdlUrls>
                    <packageName>com.bluewalrus</packageName>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This is a **wsImport** goal which generates artifacts from a web service. It happens before I compile my project. How on earth can this XML tell me where this goal should execute? It just doesn't seem clear to me.

I mean what I am saying, is that I would expect something like "bind-to-process-resources right after goal-xyz". It all seems a bit nebulous to me.

Comment: Go check the website for the plugin, it tells you specifically what phase it binds to. Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: generate-sources. A simple google search would have answered this in a fraction of the time it took you to write this post.

Comment: Hmmm... Try gradle? OK, I'm out :p

Comment: @redFIVE I think you misunderstood the question which is essentially "what is a goal in maven". At the time I was using maven I had never understood that part either.

Comment: checking the plugins website literally tells you all these things. This really isn't a question appropriate for SO.

Comment: well then "checking the plugins website" would be the answer to my question then. That's how SO works isn't it?

Comment: I sort of answered my question. I had to write down my thoughts on my website : http://blue-walrus.com/2014/03/maven-tutorial/

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the pom.xml cannot tell you everything about how a plugin's goals are bound. A plugin can define a default lifecycle phase to bind to and this will not be reflected in the pom.xml. Looking at the documentation for the jaxws-maven-plugin I see this line for the wsimport goal:

> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: generate-sources.

You can override the lifecycle phase to bind to by adding a `<phase>` element to the plugin's `<execution>`. For example, if you wanted the goal to run right before packing the artifact (not sure why you would, but bear with me for this example) you could specify `<phase>package</phase>` after the execution `<id>`

I would recommend taking a look at the official Maven [guide to configuring plugins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) for more details.

Also you would want to read:

- [The phases's order in standard lifecycles](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html)
- [The phases's bindings for lifecycle and packaging types](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/default-bindings.html)

Comment: thanks, great explanation. But is there any way of controlling where it executes WITHIN a phase, or is that pretty much random?

Comment: I believe that the only ordering within the phase you can do is define one plugin above the other in the pom.xml. Other than that, you don't have much of a choice in which order goals will execute within a phase. The order should not be random per run - it should maintain the same order between each run.